# Bulk renaming files based on a mapping

Tags: python, mapping, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a txt file with a mapping of filenames and what I need them to be converted to. Each old_filename and new_filename is different. For example the mapping looks like the following:

```
{Matt's Resorts Owner Trust 2015-1 Servicer Report 06.30.16.xlsx: MATT_15-1_201607_Servicer Report.XLSX, 
 Matt's Resorts Owner Trust 2015-1 Servicer Report 06.30.16.pdf: MATT_15-1_201607_Servicer Report.PDF, 
 CAP 2012-B 0616.xlsx: CAP_12-B_201607_Servicer Report.XLSX}
```

old_filename = Matt's Resorts Owner Trust 2015-1 Servicer Report 06.30.16.xlsx

new_filename = MATT_15-1_201607_Servicer Report.XLSX

I am trying to write a Python script that looks at each mapping and renames all of the files in that directory based on the above mapping.

I believe this should be a for loop that looks at each line and renames each file. Does anyone have some sample code that might be able to help?